# Uniqueness of doubly stochastic matrix descomposition

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, graph-theory

this is my first question in the site. Thanks in advance for all answers. 
It is well known that each bistochastic matrix can be represented as a convex combination of permutation matrices. I am looking for some criterion for unique convex representation. 
First I thought that if the bistochastic matrix is a covex combination of only two permutation matrices, then the decomposition must be unique. But then, consider this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} &0  
\end{pmatrix}

It can be expressed as the convex combination of the following two matrices (with coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$):

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 &1 &0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 &0 &0  \end{pmatrix}

and, also can be written as the convex combination of the following two matrices (with coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$):

\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1 &0  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 &0 &0  \end{pmatrix}

So, I am wrong, but can't find the mistake.
Thanks a lot for all your help.
All the best,
Juan

**SECOND PART**
The reference is the book ''Asratian, Armen S. Bipartite graphs and their applications. No. 131. Cambridge University Press, 1998,'' and in particular section 9.2.

Consider a doubly stochastic matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$, with a convex representation: $A=c_1 T_1+c_1 T_1+\ldots+c_k T_k$, where $T_r=[t_{ij}^{(r)} ]$ is a permutation matrix, $1 \leq r \leq k$.

Now, associated with each permutation matrix $T_r=[t_{ij}^{(r)} ]$ there is the corresponding permutation $\pi_r$ where $t_{i\pi_r(i)}$ is the unique element in row $i$ of $T_r$ which is $1$.

Then we have the following **theorem**:

Let $A$ be a doubly stochastic matrix of order $n$ which has a convex representation (as before) where $k \geq 2$. Then, the representation is a unique convex representation of $A$ if and only if the following two conditins hold:

1. There is at most one cycle of length more than 2 in the permutation \begin{pmatrix} \pi_a(1) & \pi_a(2) & \ldots & \pi_a(n) \\ \pi_b(1) & \pi_b(2) & \ldots & \pi_b(n) \end{pmatrix}
   for each $1 \leq  a < b \leq k$.
2. If $k \geq 3$ then for any $1 \leq a  < b < c \leq k$, the three numbers $\pi_a(i), \pi_b(i)$ and $\pi_c(i)$, are distinct for at most one $i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Now, going back to the example, and considering the following representation (with coefficient $\frac{1}{2}$):

$T_1$= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 &1 &0  \end{pmatrix} 
$T_2$= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 &0 &0  \end{pmatrix}

Since in the example $k=2$, condition 2 holds trivially. Now, for condition 1 we have the following permutations: $\pi_1(1)=1, \pi_1(2)=4, \pi_1(3)=2, \pi_1(4)=3$, and $\pi_2(1)=3,\pi_2(2)=2,\pi_2(3)=4, \pi_2(4)=1$. Clearly, condition 1 also holds because at most it may exist only one cycle with length more than $2$. Clearly, I am don't understanding the theorem, because the representation is not unique. Perhaps I am missing something with the reordering of therms. Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Doubly stochastic matrices form a polytope, whose vertices are permutation matrices. So, if your matrix lies on an *edge* of that polytope, than the representation is unique, but otherwise you really can't say much.

Comment: Yes, I do agree. Thanks! But, in the example the doubly stochastic matrix lies on a edge, and however the representation is not unique, as I show. There is something I am not understanding. Sorry and many thanks Igor!

Comment: If it can be written as two different combinations, it _does not_ lie on an edge.

Comment: @user1551 Correct, my statement is only true in one direction (for representations as sum of two things, not convex combinations in general). Think of a convex quadrilateral. If you join to opposite vertices by a segments, most points on that segment can only be written as a combination of two vertices in one way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @IgorRivin and user1551. I uderstand. My question raises because I found a theorem in the book "Asratian, Armen S. Bipartite graphs and their applications. No. 131. Cambridge University Press, 1998.", Theorem 9.2.2 page 168, that guarantees the uniqueness of the representation. The problem is that when I try to use the result in my example, the example verifies the condition to be a unique representation. Obviously, I am not understanding the theorem. Many thanks!!

Comment: Moreover, the statement is an "in and only if", but I don't really finish to understand it. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: @Juan why don't you tell us what the statement is _exactly_?

Comment: Dear @IgorRivin, I'm sorry! yes, I will explain the statement in detail tomorrow, so perhaps you may help me. All the best!

Comment: I just wrote the complete statement, and a detailed formulation of my "problem". Many thanks!

Comment: OK, I will ponder. It seems strange...

Comment: Thanks in advance Igor! I really dont know where the mistake in my reasoning is.

Comment: Dear @Igor. Finally, I know where the problem is. Professor Armen Asratian told me that there is a misprint in the condition 1 of Theorem 9.2.2 in the book.

The correct formulation of the condition 1 in the theorem will be the following:

(1) There is at most one cycle of length more than 1 in the permutation (….) for each $1\leq a < b \leq k$.

or 

(1) There is at most one cycle of length  at least  2 in the permutation (….) for each $1\leq a<b \leq k$.


Thanks for your help. Best regards.

Comment: @Juan Ah, thanks! Does it all make sense now?

Comment: sorry for the delay in my response. Yes! now it's all clear. Thanks for your help. All the best!